# I am writing a program to act like a CoinStar. Whenever I type my sentinel 'done' there is an error

Tags: java

`String termination;

```
    do {
        System.out.println("Begin Transaction!");

        int coinNumber;
        String deposit;

        do{
            System.out.print(">>");
            coinNumber = input.nextInt();
            deposit = input.nextLine();

            int search = deposit.indexOf(" ", 0);
            String denominations = deposit.substring(search +1);

            if (coinNumber < 0){
                System.out.println("Error! Please deposit positive number.");
            }

            else if (denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("quarter") || denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("quarters")){
                Customer.insertQuarters(coinNumber);
            }

            else if (denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("dime") || denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("dimes")){
                Customer.insertDimes(coinNumber);
            }

            else if (denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("nickels") || denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("nickels")){
                Customer.insertNickles(coinNumber);
            }

            else if (denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("penny") || denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("pennies")){
                Customer.insertPennies(coinNumber);
            }

            else if (denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("quarter") || !denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("quarters")
                    || !denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("dime") || !denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("dimes")
                    || !denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("nickel") || !denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("nickels")
                    || !denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("penny") || !denominations.equalsIgnoreCase("pennies")
                    || !deposit.equalsIgnoreCase("done")){
                System.out.println("Error! Please deposit correct denominations.");
            }
        } while (!deposit.contains("done"));    

        System.out.println(Customer.getVoucher());

        System.out.print("Would you like to start another transaction (y/n): ");
        termination = input.nextLine();
    }
    while (termination.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));



    System.out.println(Customer.getCollectedFees());
    input.close();
}
```

}`

I need it to be were user inputs: (4 quarters) and as many deposits as they want. Then, types 'done' without having lines in between the deposits.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYuhi.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Uhu, post code instead of snapshot.

Comment: Your code is expecting an int so it chokes on "done". You can either rethink the flow, or enter "0 done".

Comment: I am still stuck. Someone mentioned that I should do an if loop that contains input.hasNextInt, but it keeps failing. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The carriage return character isn't absorbed when you make a call to `nextInt()`. Try placing a `Scanner.nextLine()` right after your initialize `coinNumber`:

```
coinNumber = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
deposit = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I do that the program runs: Begin transaction. >>4 quarters. then next line is blank were I can type done but I need it to take as many deposits as the user wants. Then, when ready all they have to do is type 'done'.